# Firebase default VALUE parameter not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have added a event for firebase analytics. I have used default value parameter but it is not showing in actual event tab. It is working in debug view.

I have checked following links :

-- [value parameter not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513308/value-parameter-not-displayed)

-- [Firebase Analytics, unable to view the values that are passed in the event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125537/firebase-analytics-unable-to-view-the-values-that-are-passed-in-the-event)

> But I am passing numeric value only and still it is not working.

**My code :**

```
  FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalyticsStores = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(DialogActivity.this);
   Bundle params = new Bundle();
   params.putString(Constants.PARAM_af_id, AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().getAppsFlyerUID(this));
   params.putString(Constants.PARAM_dev_key, MyApplication.getAfDevKey());
   params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CURRENCY, "SGD");
   params.putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, getIntent().getDoubleExtra(EXTRA_PURCHASE_AMOUNT, 0.00));
   mFirebaseAnalyticsStores.logEvent(Constants.EVENT_begin_checkout, params);
```

**Debug view image :**

[image]

**Live event :**

[image]

Please suggest if you have tried this parameter.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. After some investigation, I've recognized a warning in the debug terminal, which told me that null values are not allowed as parameter. So if any of your bundle parameter is null, none of the bundle parameters are applied and send.

```
//key_1 and key_2 will be sent
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("key_1", "val_1");
params.putString("key_2", "val_2");
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("event_1", params);

//No parameter will be sent
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("key_1", "val_1");
params.putString("key_2", null);
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("event_1", params);
```

So you need to ensure, that none of the strings in you bundle is null.